The resistors in the LED strip are burning out
I have a PCB with two series and six parallel LEDs, totaling 12 LEDs. Each 2835 SMD LED operates at 6V, 160mA, and 0.9W. As you calculate total consumption is 12V and 960mA.
Since our supply is 24V, I added resistors in each parallel circuit.
According to the calculations, I have to use 75ohm
(Vs - Vf / Ic )
12/0.16 = 75 ohm
When I added 75 ohms to each circuit and supplied it with 24V, smoke emerged from the resistors. So, I increased the resistor value to 330 ohms, and although they still get hot, they work fine.
The values I read from Dc Power Supply is 24V and 0.24A.
I dont understand how could it works with 330ohm And does it still work if i supply it with 24V adapter?

Can you reconfigure for 3S4P and get 18 V Vf instead? Or put all in series and use a boost converter with constant current output?

You got smoke because those resistors have to dissipate over 12W (>12V times 1A). You did not use resistors large enough. Use 20W resistors mounted on a heatsink and you’ll have no problem :)
The larger value (330Ω) resistors did not burn up because there was quite a bit less current flowing through them. The circuit did not “work” because not enough current was flowing through the LEDs relative to what you said you needed (960mA ≈ 1A). Sure the LEDs were lit, but you said you wanted them working at 1A.
Or use a proper LED driver instead of a fixed-voltage supply.
